# image update with other related records in sql database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, image, gridview

I have a table called Phase it contains other columns and also an image column. All is working fine except that when i want to update the image it says " i cannot implicitly convert nvarchar to varbinary(max) and also when i want to update any one of the columns apart from the image it shows me the same error. Please help me out what am i doing wrong? Below is my aspx and aspx.cs codes respectively:

```
protected void gv1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    int index = e.RowIndex;

    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)gv1.Rows[index];

    Label eid = (Label)row.FindControl("lbleid");
    TextBox date = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtdate");
    DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ProjectID");
    DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ProjectTypeID");
    DropDownList ddl3 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("StateID");
    DropDownList ddl4 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("LGAID");
    DropDownList ddl5 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("CommunityID");
    DropDownList ddl6 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("CoyID");

    FileUpload fu = (FileUpload)row.FindControl("fu1");

    foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in fu.PostedFiles)

    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
        string contentType = postedFile.ContentType;
        using (Stream fs = postedFile.InputStream)

        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {

                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Phase set Photo = '" + fu.FileName + "' where Phase_1ID=" + Convert.ToInt32(eid.Text) + "", con);

                con.Open();
                int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("update Phase set DateOfVisit='" + date.Text + "', ProjectTitle='" + ddl1.Text + "', Type='" + ddl2.Text + "', StateName='" + ddl3.Text + "', LGName='" + ddl4.Text + "', CommunityName='" + ddl5.Text + "', CompanyName='" + ddl6.Text + "", con);
            con.Open();
            int res1 = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            if (res1 == 1)
            {

                Response.Write("<script>alert('Updation done!')</script>");

            }

            gv1.EditIndex = -1;

            gv1.DataBind();

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If `Photo` is the Image column, you are trying to store a string instead of a byte array (binary data). What do you want to store, the image file name or the image content? If you want to store the file name change the column type to varchar, if you want to store the image data then read the image file and use it as the content. Also, you will need a parameterized query as binary data can't be concatenated on the query string.

Comment: @Gusman, tnx. please give a sample